# GMAIL vba to get current user and return User's Gmail Address

Tags: excel, gmail, vba

I have code that generates a GMail Email from within Excel VBA, however, I am looking for code that will determine who the current user is and return the current user's Gmail Email address.

Comment: determine who the current user of what is? computer user? Or current person logged into gmail?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a way to get GMAIL address from code, unless they have a browser window open to their GMAIL account

Microsoft sample code to get current username

```
' Makes sure all variables are dimensioned in each subroutine.
 Option Explicit

 ' Access the GetUserNameA function in advapi32.dll and
 ' call the function GetUserName.
 Declare Function GetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "GetUserNameA" _
 (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long

 ' Main routine to Dimension variables, retrieve user name
 ' and display answer.
 Sub Get_User_Name()

 ' Dimension variables
 Dim lpBuff As String * 25
 Dim ret As Long, UserName As String

 ' Get the user name minus any trailing spaces found in the name.
 ret = GetUserName(lpBuff, 25)
 UserName = Left(lpBuff, InStr(lpBuff, Chr(0)) - 1)

 ' Display the User Name
 MsgBox UserName
 End Sub
```

Comment: It's got nothing to do with any email client - it retrieves the current computer username

Comment: However, I am looking for the current user's Gmail Email address.

Comment: You should edit your request - currently is says both current user AND Gmal address. ** .."determine who the current user is and return the current user's Gmail Email address"**. As I said you won't find a VBA function to get the GMAIL address, unless you want to ask the user from it and store it in a text file or databae for later

Comment: for future reference  `UserName = ENVIRON("username")` is a much simpler way to get the username :)